# Oracle : Decode for more than one key field

Tags: sql, oracle, decode

I have table

```
Date_pkp  | date_pkp_delete | status
<null>    |  <null>         |
10.10.2000| 20.11.2009      |
12.10.2005| <null>          |
```

If 'Date_pkp' is null AND 'date_pkp_delete' is null then 'status' = Non PKP

If 'Date_pkp' is not null AND 'date_pkp_delete' is not null, then 'status' = Non PKP

If 'Date_pkp' is not null AND 'date_pkp_delete' is null, then 'status' = PKP

How to query with `decode`?

SELECT date_pkp, date_pkp_delete, Decode(...) status from table

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It would be easier to do this with a `case` expression:

```
SELECT date_pkp,
       date_pkp_delete
       CASE WHEN ((date_pkp IS NULL AND date_pkp_delete IS NULL) OR
                  (date_pkp IS NOT NULL AND date_pkp_delete IS NOT NULL))
            THEN 'Non PKP'
            WHEN (date_pkp IS NOT NULL AND date_pkp_delete IS NULL)
            THEN 'PKP'
       END AS status
FROM   my_table
```

Answer (score 1):

Since you have to check multiple conditions, instead of writing complected decode, use case statement as follows:

```
select DATE_PKP, DATE_PKP_DELETE, case when (DATE_PKP is null and DATE_PKP_DELETE is null) then  'Non PKP'
                                       when (DATE_PKP is not null and DATE_PKP_DELETE is not null) then 'Non PKP'
                                       when (DATE_PKP is not null and DATE_PKP_DELETE is null) then 'PKP status' 
                                   end STATUS
from table;
```